# Deleting "Method in protocol not implemented" warnings

Tags: objective-c, methods, protocols, categories, required

Imagine you want to declare a new protocol and define a default behavior for it by implementing its methods on a "base" class.
If you don't own the implementation files for this class (e.g. NSObject), you may want to implement the protocol's methods via a category.
This might lead you to something similar to the following piece of code:

```
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    *      Formal Protocol
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

    @protocol MyProto <NSObject>

    - (void) myMethod;

    @end



   /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    *      Informal Protocol (a Category Interface)
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

    @interface NSObject (MyProto)
        <MyProto>
    @end



   /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    *      Category Implementation
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

    @implementation NSObject (MyProto)

    - (void) myMethod {
        return;
    }
```

It does not compile properly, and produce several warning around the line

```
@implementation NSObject (MyProto)
```

> (Semantic Issue)
>
> - Method in protocol not implemented
>
>   - Method declared here
>   - Required for direct or indirect protocol 'NSObject'

To suppress these warnings just remove the mention to the NSObject protocol in your protocol declaration

```
    @protocol MyProto

    - (void) myMethod;

    @end
```

this will prevents the linker from re-requiring the NSObject protocol's methods in your category implementation.

Comment: So, what is the question being asked here?

Comment: It's implicitly expressed in the title : "how to delete a certain warning ?" I was about to _really_ ask the question on here when I found the solution I mentioned. I posted it in the hope that some day it will avoid someone to ask this very question.

Comment: You should post a question and then post an answer to your own question and accept it in situations like this. Answering inside a question is not really welcome here as you can see :)